# map nullable int to nullable int + automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, automapper

I need to map a nullable int to a nullable int via autompper

This my class Incident:

```
public class Incident : Evenement
{
    public Incident()
        : base(-1, Global.EvenementType.Incidents, DateTime.MinValue)
    {
    }

    public Incident(int id, DateTime date, string libelle,  int formulaireId,  string societe, string userName)
        : base(id, (int)Global.EvenementType.Incidents, date, libelle, "", "", societe)
    {
        ContratId = formulaireId;
        Contrat = null;
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public Incident(int id, DateTime date, string libelle, string societe, string userName)
        : base(id, (int)Global.EvenementType.Incidents, date, libelle, "", "", societe)
    {
        ContratId = null;
        Contrat = null;
        UserName = userName;
    }


    [DataMember]
    public int? ContratId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Contrat Contrat { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsGeneral
```

and this is my class INCIDENT

```
 public partial class INCIDENT : EVENEMENT
    {
        public Nullable<int> FORMULAIRE_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual FORMULAIRE FORMULAIRE { get; set; }
        public string USERNAME { get; set; }
    }
```

When I'm doing a mapping and i have a null in contratId dans incident, it's automotically converted to 0 in FORMULAIRE_ID in class INCIDENT

This my bindings

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Incident, INCIDENT>()
            .ForMember(degivreuse => degivreuse.FORMULAIRE_ID, expression => expression.MapFrom(degivreuse => degivreuse.ContratId))
              .ForMember(degivreuse => degivreuse.FORMULAIRE, expression => expression.Ignore());
```

And in the PJ the problem:
[image]

Do you have any idea why i don't obtain a null value please?

Regards

Comment: Your code should successfully map null to null. I would start from checking all write usages of `FORMULAIRE_ID`. Maybe its value is changed after property mapping (in another property setter or something else?).

Comment: no it not change anywhay!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any issues with the way Automapper handles `int?`.  Here's a quick sample that works fine:

```
public class Src1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}

public class Dest1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Src1, Dest1>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var s = new Src1 {Name = "aaa", Age = null};
var d = Mapper.Map<Src1, Dest1>(s);
```

In the sample above, `d.Age` is `null`.  Can you provide some sample code that reproduces the issue you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Today I've stumbled upon the same problem with `AutoMapper 10.1.1`.
I tried to map my custom class to MarginSettings class in DinkToPdf library.
The MarginSettings class had 2 constructors:

```
    public class MarginSettings
    {
        public Unit Unit { get; set; }

        public double? Top { get; set; }

        public double? Bottom { get; set; }

        public double? Left { get; set; }

        public double? Right { get; set; }

        public MarginSettings()
        {
            Unit = Unit.Millimeters;
        }

        public MarginSettings(double top, double right, double bottom, double left) : this()
        {
            Top = top;

            Bottom = bottom;

            Left = left;

            Right = right;
        }

        // the rest of class..
}
```

It looks like for some reason AutoMapper is calling a constructor with parameters in MarginSettings class when it tries to map my custom class to it. This way, the default `double` value (0) is set to `double?` properties in this constructor.

Here is the code demonstrating this problem:

```
    class SourceClass
    {
        public double? Top { get; set; }

        public double? Bottom { get; set; }

        public double? Left { get; set; }

        public double? Right { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassWithoutCtor
    {
        public double? Top { get; set; }

        public double? Bottom { get; set; }

        public double? Left { get; set; }

        public double? Right { get; set; }
    }

    // The class similar to one in DinkToPdf library
    class ClassWithCtor
    {
        public string Message1 { get; set; }
        public string Message2 { get; set; }

        public double? Top { get; set; }

        public double? Bottom { get; set; }

        public double? Left { get; set; }

        public double? Right { get; set; }

        public ClassWithCtor() => this.Message1 = "in default ctor";

        public ClassWithCtor(double top, double right, double bottom, double left)
            : this()
        {
            this.Top = new double?(top);
            this.Bottom = new double?(bottom);
            this.Left = new double?(left);
            this.Right = new double?(right);
            Message2 = "in ctor with parameters";
        }
    }

    class AutoMapperTest
    {
        public void TryMapZeros()
        {
            var source = new SourceClass
            {
                Top = 5,
                Bottom = 5
            };

            var mapConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, ClassWithoutCtor>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, ClassWithCtor>();
                }
                );

            var mapper = mapConfiguration.CreateMapper();
            var margin1 = mapper.Map<SourceClass, ClassWithoutCtor>(source);
            var margin2 = mapper.Map<SourceClass, ClassWithCtor>(source);
        }
    }
```

The mapped objects look this way after the code execution:

```
margin1
{PdfGeneratorTest.ClassWithoutCtor}
    Bottom: 5
    Left: null
    Right: null
    Top: 5
margin2
{PdfGeneratorTest.ClassWithCtor}
    Bottom: 5
    Left: 0
    Message1: "in default ctor"
    Message2: "in ctor with parameters"
    Right: 0
    Top: 5
```